# Update a cell in a corresponding row if information is found in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet of users  with 7 columns.

The first column contains the user's email address. The other 6 columns contain data that is TRUE or FALSE.

I want to scan a different sheet for a matching email address, and, if it is found, update a cell in a single column on the first sheet that is in the row that the matching email address was found.

The second sheet only contains email addresses.

I have a fairly basic understanding of how to use IF and VLOOKUP, but I just cannot devise a way to do this.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Excel Sheet Before

[image]

Excel Sheet After

[image]

XLS List of Email Addresses

[image]

I've tried `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,BulkImportTemplate.csv!$A:$A,1,FALSE),FALSE,TRUE)`, but it just replaces everything in the cells with #N/A if the email address isn't found.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of Excel just won't cut what I want to do.

Comment: Please mock up some data in tabular form.  Then [edit] the post to include that mock up, the expected result using that data, and what you have tried to this point that is not working.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question, and added some information on what I want things to end up like.

Comment: Use COUNTIF instead : `=COUNTIF(BulkImportTemplate.csv!$A:$A,A2)>0`

Comment: Ok,, but will that update the data in all rows, or only the rows that matched the email address found?

Comment: I will return true if the email in `A2` is found anywhere in `BulkImportTemplate.csv!$A:$A`  You would need to copy that formula down so it would then refer to A3, A4 and so on.

Comment: My problem is that I have 500 users I have to look up and compare to a sheet that has thousands of users.... I can just update things manually that way, and it will take less time...